# Jquery removeClass isn't working

Tags: jquery

I have here two scripts. I had datepicker ui.jquery. What I need to do is removeClass datepicker if the value of selectbox is changed. But it doesn't working. Why is that? Here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aLgh2/3/.

```
$("#tag").change(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() != "") {
    $("#pr_date").removeClass('datepicker');
    $("#gss_date").removeClass('datepicker');
    $(".readonly").prop('readonly', 'true');

} else {
    $("#pr_date").addClass('datepicker');
    $("#gss_date").addClass('datepicker');
    $(".readonly").prop('readonly', 'false');    
    }   
});



$(function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true
});
});
```

Comment: `.prop('readonly', 'true');` should be `.prop('readonly', true);` [true should not be quoted]

Comment: Instead of just removing class, you need to disable plugin as suggested in DOC: `.datepicker('disable');`  So, basically, you should read the DOC...

Comment: Your question is not clear, but it looks like you think datepicker widgets can come and go according to their element's classes. That's not the case.

Comment: @C-link copy that my fault. But why removeclass isn't working?

Comment: Class is getting removed, but Datepicker appends its own class **hasdatepicker**. You cannot undo the Datepicker function by just `.removeClass()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use instead:

### --DEMO--

```
$("#tag").change(function () {
    if (this.value) {
        $("#pr_date, #gss_date").datepicker('disable');
        $(".readonly").prop('readonly', true);

    } else {
        $("#pr_date, #gss_date").datepicker('enable');
        $(".readonly").prop('readonly', false);
    }
});
```

Now you can still refactorize you code a little:

```
$("#tag").change(function () {
    var val = this.value;
    $("#pr_date, #gss_date").datepicker(val ? 'disable' : 'enable');
    $(".readonly").prop('readonly', !!val);
});
```

Comment: One thing, I tried before to disabled a textbox field but after I submit and post it into another page that has a process of insert into database, the fields that disabled was empty. No value was post.

Comment: @user3631428 Ya, that's the expected behaviour. If you want to send it, before serialize FORM data, switch `disable` attribute

Comment: I am right. I try to input a information but the disabled fields was empty in the database.

Comment: Pardon me but how I can switch that in jquery?

Comment: Just like you did for `readonly` property/attribute. You can switch it inside submit event of FORM

Comment: I try like this <script>
$("form#register_form").submit(function() {
$("#pr_date, #gss_date").prop('disable', false);
});
</script> but doesn't working.

Comment: @user3631428 Something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/aLgh2/10/  Would be a little different if you are submitting FORM using ajax

Comment: Okay I got it. It should be placed at bottom of the form I am right?

Comment: You have to bind event after FORM is available in the DOM, like any other event or delegate it

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quotes from `true` and `false` as A.Wolff suggested.
It works fine in fiddle, try it.

it should be like

```
$(".readonly").prop('readonly', true);
```

and

```
$(".readonly").prop('readonly', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working.  It is actually removing the class.  However, the widget already exists so you can't just remove the class.  Try changing your removeClass lines to:

```
$("#pr_date").datepicker( "destroy" );
$("#gss_date").datepicker( "destroy" );
```